# Преобразовать сет (Python)

Tags: python, set

Есть сет

```
set = {'lol', 'kek', 'cheburek'}
```

Как мне вывести в нужном мне порядке
к примеру что бы было в принте

> ```
> 'cheburek', 'lol', 'kek'
> ```

**НУЖНО** что бы в принте, не было скобок типа `( ) [ ] { }`.

Только такой вывод 'cheburek', 'lol', 'kek'

Comment: вы можете описать этот нужный вам порядок? Почему именно так `'cheburek', 'lol', 'kek'` надо вывести, а например не так `'kek', 'cheburek', 'lol'` ?

Comment: мне кажется, вы не знаете основ языка, раз просите чтобы при принте не выводилась синтаксическая конструкция декларирования множества............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: @finally после прочтения вашего комментария, мне кажется что я не знаю основ

Comment: скобки всегда будут? Да я не знаю, я учусь только

Comment: скобки это моя жизнь, скообкииии, а если серьезно, то это лишь синт конструкция, чтоб дать понять интерпретатору, что вы вообще имеете в виду, и нет, они не хранятся нигде, это способ задания множества

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set_ = {'lol', 'kek', 'cheburek'}
print(sorted(set_, key=lambda x: x[2]))
# ['cheburek', 'kek', 'lol']
print(sorted(set_, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True))
# ['lol', 'kek', 'cheburek']
print(*sorted(set_, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True), sep=', ')
# lol, kek, cheburek
print(', '.join(sorted(set_, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)))
# lol, kek, cheburek
print("'" + "', '".join(sorted(set_, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)) + "'")
# 'lol', 'kek', 'cheburek'
```

Comment: НУЖНО что бы в принте, не было скобок типа " ( ) [ ] { } " Только такой вывод 'cheburek', 'lol', 'kek'

Comment: @Alex `print(*sorted(set, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True), sep=', ')`

Comment: нету кавычек 'lol'

Comment: "Houston, we have a problem"

Comment: @Alex, последнюю строку глянте. Так?

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо большое

Comment: @Wairua Забыли про `repr` :)

Answer (score 1):

странное желание сортировать множества.. но допустим:

```
>>>elements = {'lol', 'kek', 'cheburek'}
>>>print(sorted(elements, key=lambda x: x[0]))
['cheburek', 'kek', 'lol']
>>>
```

тут сортировка идет по первому элементу строки..

но в вашем примере сортировка идет вообще не пойму по какому правилу, так что пути два:

-**смириться с порядком букв в алфавите**

-*придумать свое правило, и переопределить функцию sort()*

Comment: Строй именно такой нужен. У вас в принте скобки выдало
['cheburek', 'kek', 'lol']
Нужно сделать именно так как я показал.
Преобразовать в список мб или картеж -не знаю, вот спрашиваю

Comment: @Alex распишите подробнее, ни*** не понятно, но очень интересно

Comment: Да подробнее некуда)
Задание , есть вот такой сет, нужно сделать из него 'cheburek', 'kek', 'lol'
и именно так, ни как по другому

Comment: @finally. Присодинюсь к просьбе)))

Comment: По третьей букве сортируйте

Comment: @Alex вы путаетесь в показаниях, то вам надо  'cheburek', 'lol', 'kek', то  'cheburek', 'kek', 'lol'.. вы уж определитесь..

Comment: А может человеку просто по индексам выписать?

Comment: @finally пофиг, тогда по третье букве в обратном порядке

Answer (score 0):

```
set = {'lol', 'kek', 'cheburek'}
print(set[2], set[0], set[1], sep ='\n')
```

Comment: Так сет постоянно меняется. Нужно его сделать статичным и именно в таком порядке

Comment: постоянно или просто в своей чуднОй манере?

Comment: Что бы был статичным. Да знаю, странное задание. Но так надо.

Comment: Какие ещё индексы в множестве? Вы бы хоть попробовали ваш код запустить.